# Changing field settings after data being saved in drupal 7

Tags: php, timezone, field, drupal-7

One of my content types has the field Date and time. When it was created the wrong settings were set and it is now not possible to change these because there's data for the field saved in the database. The field is Date and time which makes it easier to pick date and time. How can I change these settings without having to make a new field with correct settings. Where can I find the settings in the database and manually change it? Screenshot of the settings i can't change:
http://d.pr/MT3r

The problem is that the Time zone is set to Site's time zone and somehow it doesn't match with the time zone set in the Site configuration. I need to change this to "No time zone".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up using my own timezone conversion:

```
    $event_from_timezone = new DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone());
    $event_from_date = new DateTime($node->field_date['und'][0]['value'], $event_from_timezone);
    $event_from_offset = $event_from_timezone->getOffset($event_from_date);
    $event_from_datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i', $event_from_date->format('U') + $event_from_offset);
```

Which works perfectly. Dunno why Drupal 7 couldn't do this itself.